Button click event triggered after pointer down in a div with setPointerCapture and release over button – Why?
I have a simple web page with a button and a div. The button has a click event listener that logs to the console when clicked. The div has a pointerdown event listener that calls setPointerCapture to capture pointer events.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devicexx-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>play</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn">Test</button>
<div id="div" style="margin-top: 20px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background: red"></div>

<script>
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("btn clicked"));

  const div = document.getElementById("div");
  div.addEventListener("pointerdown", (e) => {
    e.target.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>

On Firefox, when I press mouse on the div, drag it onto the button and release it over the button, the button's click event fires. This issue doesn't happen on Edge, Safari and Chrome.
I wonder why it happens? How can I prevent the click event fires?
I tried to manually remove that pointer capture when pointer up like this:
div.addEventListener("pointerup", (e) => {
  e.target.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
});

It doesn't help.
PS: If you want to know why I want to prevent it, it's because it's related to this issue: https://github.com/radix-ui/primitives/issues/2777.

did you try  e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropagation();?
div.addEventListener("pointerup", (e) => {
e.stopPropagation()
e.target.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
});

@ab_qayyum Yes I've tried both, but still no luck.

This erroneous behavior is a currently known bug.
A click event is a mouse/pointer down & mouse/pointer up on the same element.
Let's change your code a bit.
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <title>play</title>
</head><body style="border: 1px solid black;">
<button id="btn" style="margin: 10px; width: 50px;">Test</button>
<div id="div" style="margin: 10px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background: red"></div>
<script>
  function report( e ) {
    console.log( this.tagName, e.target.tagName, e.type );
  }

  const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener( 'click',       report );
  btn.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', report );
  btn.addEventListener( 'pointerup',   report );

  const div = document.getElementById( 'div' );
  div.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', e => {
    console.log( 'DIV', e.target.tagName, e.type );
    e.target.setPointerCapture( e.pointerId );
  } );
  div.addEventListener( 'pointerup', report );
  div.addEventListener( 'click',     report );

  document.body.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', report );
  document.body.addEventListener( 'pointerup',   report );
  document.body.addEventListener( 'click',       report );
</script>
</body></html>

The code above allows trying various things. For example

Down & hold on the div, then drag & up to the right (body) correctly directs the target of the up event at the div, as it should with the pointer events captured there. Because the down event on the div bubbled up to the body, there's a click on the body, but the click should be on the div.
DIV  DIV  pointerdown
BODY DIV  pointerdown
DIV  DIV  pointerup
BODY DIV  pointerup
BODY BODY click

The click should be:
DIV  DIV click
BODY DIV click


Down & hold on the body, then drag & up on the div correctly reports the target of the up event as the div, because that's where the up event took place. The up event bubbles to the body, so there's a click event on the body.
BODY BODY pointerdown
DIV  DIV  pointerup
BODY DIV  pointerup
BODY BODY click


Similarly down & hold on the body, then drag & up to the button correctly reports the target of the up event as the button. Again the up event bubbles, so there's a click on the body.
BODY   BODY   pointerdown
BUTTON BUTTON pointerup
BODY   BUTTON pointerup
BODY   BODY   click


However, down & hold on the div, then drag & up to the button correctly reports the up event on the div like it should, but also Firefox appears to be confused that the down and (captured) up events took place on the same element (the div), but the pointer is over the button. There should be no click event on the button.
DIV    DIV    pointerdown
BODY   DIV    pointerdown
DIV    DIV    pointerup
BODY   DIV    pointerup
BUTTON BUTTON click
BODY   BUTTON click

As in #1, the click should be:
DIV  DIV click
BODY DIV click



Here's a work-around, if you're desperate, to find the common ancestor of the pointerdown and pointerup events. (It won't work with keyboard navigation, only pointers.) It would be better if Mozilla fixed the bug so clicks worked with setPointerCapture.
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <title>play</title>
</head><body style="border: 1px solid black;">
<button id="btn" style="margin: 10px; width: 50px;">Test</button>
<div id="div" style="margin: 10px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background: red"></div>
<script>( function () {
  'use strict';

  var
    div = document.getElementById( 'div' ),
    pathDown = [];

  function findClick( e ) {
    var
      target, found, i;

    console.log( e.type, 'on', e.target.tagName );
    if ( e.type === 'pointerdown' ) {
      // record the path of ancestors from the target to the root
      pathDown = [];
      for ( target = e.target; target; target = target.parentElement ) {
        pathDown.push( target );
      }
    } else { // pointerup
      found = false;
      // look for the first common ancestor between the "down" event and the "up" event
      for ( target = e.target; target && !found; target = target.parentElement ) {
        for ( i = 0; i < pathDown.length && !found; ++i ) {
          if ( target === pathDown[ i ] ) {
            found = target;
          }
        }
      }
      pathDown = [];
      if ( found ) {
        console.log( 'click on', found.tagName );
      }
    }
  }
  // listen on the body, because everything bubbles up eventually
  document.body.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', findClick );
  document.body.addEventListener( 'pointerup',   findClick );

  div.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', e => {
    e.target.setPointerCapture( e.pointerId );
  } );
} () );</script>
</body></html>


Thanks for Nanigashi. I've found that this is indeed a Firefox issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1556240. It has been discussed in: https://github.com/w3c/pointerevents/issues/356
I'd like to propose another work-round: You can use pointer-events properties to temporarily disable pointer events of a component. Be cautious though. It might cause unexpected side effect.
div.addEventListener("pointerdown", (e) => {
  document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  e.target.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
});

div.addEventListener("pointerup", (e) => {
  e.target.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
  document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
});


After digging around on Bugzilla a little more, it appears that this bug is being worked as Bugzilla 1885232 with the rather non-obvious name "Failing WPTs in /pointerevents/pointerevent_click_during_capture.html?mouse-[click|auxclick]." I'll update my answer to refer to that bug.

The difficulty with disabling all pointer events is that it still doesn't register a click on the div, even if you just click (down/up) and don't do down/drag/up. It might work for you this time, but others encountering the bug may need a different solution. (Aside: it's interesting that capturing the pointer on the div keeps events enabled there when they're disabled everywhere else.)
